# Any way to install Pandas with PyPy?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, compiler-optimization, pypy

I'm trying to run some code using **PyPy** to speed it up. My code uses **Pandas** dataframes, so I'm trying to find a way to install the package...

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do that... searching online yields [this](http://www.anlytcs.com/2014/01/how-i-reduced-my-data-crunching-time.html) and [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9532) --  two disappointing results which say it's not possible, but they are **1-2 years old!**

There was a glimmer of hope from [this twitter post from Romain Guillebert](https://twitter.com/rguillebert/status/624883134258130944) which suggests I could do it using a package called **[pymetabiosis](https://github.com/rguillebert/pymetabiosis)**. Unfortunately when I go to install that, I get the error mentioned below.

**Any idea how I can debug the error or find some other way of using Pandas with PyPy**?**

---

Error message when installing **pymetabiosis:**

```
Collecting pymetabiosis
  Using cached pymetabiosis-0.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    pymetabiosis/__pycache__/_cffi__x771a6f66x197b9d2b.c:219:13: warning: initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'const char **' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      { char * *tmp = &p->ml_name; (void)tmp; }
                ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    pymetabiosis/__pycache__/_cffi__x771a6f66x197b9d2b.c:220:13: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'void **' with an expression of type 'PyCFunction *' (aka 'struct _object *(**)(struct _object *, struct _object *)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      { void * *tmp = &p->ml_meth; (void)tmp; }
                ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    pymetabiosis/__pycache__/_cffi__x771a6f66x197b9d2b.c:222:13: warning: initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'const char **' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      { char * *tmp = &p->ml_doc; (void)tmp; }
                ^     ~~~~~~~~~~
    pymetabiosis/__pycache__/_cffi__x771a6f66x197b9d2b.c:1189:30: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') to parameter of type 'PyCodeObject *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      { result = PyEval_EvalCode(x0, x1, x2); }
                                 ^~
    //anaconda/include/python2.7/eval.h:10:54: note: passing argument to parameter here
    PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyEval_EvalCode(PyCodeObject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);
                                                         ^
    pymetabiosis/__pycache__/_cffi__x771a6f66x197b9d2b.c:1857:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
      { result = PyObject_SetAttr(x0, x1, x2); }
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    pymetabiosis/__pycache__/_cffi__x771a6f66x197b9d2b.c:2164:5: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'PyObject *(*)(size_t, ...)' (aka 'struct _object *(*)(unsigned long, ...)') from 'PyObject *(Py_ssize_t, ...)' (aka 'struct _object *(long, ...)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      i = (PyTuple_Pack);
        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    6 warnings generated.
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L//anaconda/lib
    '
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/t4/n42mh55n05sd6s5hgk1dzdz80000gp/T/pip-build-fSTXPd/pymetabiosis/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        from pymetabiosis.bindings import ffi
      File "pymetabiosis/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pymetabiosis.module import import_module
      File "pymetabiosis/module.py", line 2, in <module>
        from pymetabiosis.wrapper import MetabiosisWrapper
      File "pymetabiosis/wrapper.py", line 3, in <module>
        from __pypy__ import identity_dict
    ImportError: No module named __pypy__

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code -11 in /private/var/folders/t4/n42mh55n05sd6s5hgk1dzdz80000gp/T/pip-build-fSTXPd/pymetabiosis/
```

Comment: pypy still conflicts with pandas.

Comment: @kilojoules :( (but thanks for letting me know)

Comment: ``PyDateTime_GET_MONTH(val) = -1;`` looks like the error posted on http://packages.pypy.org/##pandas .  If that's all, someone should fix that.  Contributions welcome!

Comment: @Afflatus did you eventually install pandas over pypy?

Comment: @NI6 don't remember but I doubt it.

Comment: coming back to this Q after much more experience with pandas/python, i highly doubt that using PyPy will speed up pandas, as most of the core pandas routines are written in C and highly performant when used correctly. I.e. it's highly unlikely you will see large performance gains when using PyPy version of pandas, since it's probably the same underlying C code anyway. Quick google will show you how to correctly use Pandas in cpython fastly.

Comment: Yes, pandas is still not building for pypy3 V7.3.7 (python 3.8.12)

Comment: @0xc0de what about  PyPy v7.3.9?

Answer (score 12):

[pypy v5.9](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/release-v5.9.0.html#pypy2-7-and-pypy3-5-v5-9-dual-release) has started to support pandas (and numpy)

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I've done, assume you're using Conda, but Pip/Venv should work also

Make a new conda env

```
conda create --name pypy_env
conda activate pypy_env
```

Install pypy3 using conda

```
conda install pypy3
```

Get Pip for pypy3 using the method here [Install pip on pypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342075/install-pip-on-pypy)

Install packages for pypy using

```
pypy3 -m pip install pandas
```

Comment: Using it with pip didn't work for me. I checked PyPy's website and found this: [supported packages](http://packages.pypy.org/##python-keystoneclient). Seems like Pandas is not supported (at least not without some hacky workarounds)

Comment: FYI for anyone that found this answer useful, see my comment above on the question - but TL;DR you're unlikely to get much benefit from doing this, even if it works.

Comment: Doesn't work with pypy3 V7.3.7 (python 3.8.12)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to install and configure `pypy3` on your ubuntu/debian machine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pypy3
```

Also you could add:

```
sudo apt install pypy3-dev pypy3-venv
```

Then you could install `pandas` and `numpy` globaly:

```
pypy3 -m pip install pandas numpy
```

> Installing through `pip` may takes some minutes to complete