# "conda install" not installing to pypy

Tags: python, conda, pypy

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62186941/5411493) post I created an environment for pypy2.7: `conda create -c conda-forge -n pypy2.7 pypy2.7`. In the new environment I can now do

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/usr/bin/python
```

and

```
$ pypy -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/home/julian/miniconda2/envs/pypy2.7/bin/pypy
```

So there is no `python` in the environment, therefore the system's `python` gets used, but there is `pypy` im the environment, which is exactly what we want. Obviously if I try to

```
$ pypy
Python 2.7.13 (0e7ea4fe15e82d5124e805e2e4a37cae1a402d4b, Dec 28 2017, 20:45:53)
[PyPy 5.10.0 with GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

it does not work.

According to the post mentioned earlier, I should now be able to `conda install numpy`, however this will do:

```
conda install numpy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.8.3
  latest version: 4.10.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/julian/miniconda2/envs/pypy2.7

  added / updated specs:
    - numpy


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ca-certificates    conda-forge/linux-64::ca-certificates-2020.12.5-ha878542_0
  certifi            conda-forge/linux-64::certifi-2020.12.5-py39hf3d152e_1
  ld_impl_linux-64   conda-forge/linux-64::ld_impl_linux-64-2.35.1-hea4e1c9_2
  libblas            conda-forge/linux-64::libblas-3.9.0-8_openblas
  libcblas           conda-forge/linux-64::libcblas-3.9.0-8_openblas
  libffi             conda-forge/linux-64::libffi-3.3-h58526e2_2
  libgfortran-ng     conda-forge/linux-64::libgfortran-ng-9.3.0-hff62375_19
  libgfortran5       conda-forge/linux-64::libgfortran5-9.3.0-hff62375_19
  liblapack          conda-forge/linux-64::liblapack-3.9.0-8_openblas
  libopenblas        conda-forge/linux-64::libopenblas-0.3.12-pthreads_h4812303_1
  libstdcxx-ng       conda-forge/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng-9.3.0-h6de172a_19
  ncurses            conda-forge/linux-64::ncurses-6.2-h58526e2_4
  numpy              conda-forge/linux-64::numpy-1.20.2-py39hdbf815f_0
  openssl            conda-forge/linux-64::openssl-1.1.1k-h7f98852_0
  pip                conda-forge/noarch::pip-21.1.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  python             conda-forge/linux-64::python-3.9.2-hffdb5ce_0_cpython
  python_abi         conda-forge/linux-64::python_abi-3.9-1_cp39
  readline           conda-forge/linux-64::readline-8.1-h46c0cb4_0
  setuptools         conda-forge/linux-64::setuptools-49.6.0-py39hf3d152e_3
  sqlite             conda-forge/linux-64::sqlite-3.35.5-h74cdb3f_0
  tk                 conda-forge/linux-64::tk-8.6.10-h21135ba_1
  tzdata             conda-forge/noarch::tzdata-2021a-he74cb21_0
  wheel              conda-forge/noarch::wheel-0.36.2-pyhd3deb0d_0
  xz                 conda-forge/linux-64::xz-5.2.5-h516909a_1
```

Notice the `python   conda-forge/linux-64::python-3.9.2-hffdb5ce_0_cpython`, so instead of installing numpy to pypy, it installs a new python3.9.

And sure enough after the numpy installation I get

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
/home/julian/miniconda2/envs/pypy2.7/bin/python
```

and numpy is still not installed for pypy.

How do I get `conda install` to work on pypy instead of python?

All of this is happening on the WSL (Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conda does not support pypy2.7

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to be the case. Makes me wonder though why the pypy2.7 conda-forge package exists...

Comment: I will try to get it removed