# How to install pip

Tags: python, pip, pypy

Can you please tell me how to install 'pip' on pypy3 interpreter in windows10 64 bits.
I'm using pycharm IDE and set pypy as a IDE interpreter. But when I trying to install pandas library on pypy3 using this command

```
pypy3 pip install pandas
```

I'm getting error like this___

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pip'
```

Can you please tell me how to resolve this problem...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install pip on pypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342075/install-pip-on-pypy)

Comment: Which version of python you are using?

Comment: pip install -U pandas

Comment: [https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/] this URL has all that you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

`pypy3 -m pip install virtualenv`

Note the "`-m`". But you really do not want to try to install pandas like this: since there is no binary wheel for pypy it will compile from source, which is a mess on windows. I would suggest you wait until either pandas provides binary wheels for windows or pypy3/windows is supported on conda.