# PyPy and Python version

Tags: python, ubuntu, pypy

I have installed latest version of PyPy using `sudo apt install pypy pypy-dev` on my Xubuntu. When I try `python --version` I see that I have Python 3.8.10 installed. When I try `pypy --version` I got

```
Python 2.7.13 (7.3.1+dfsg-2, Apr 21 2020, 05:05:41)
[PyPy 7.3.1 with GCC 9.3.0]
```

Thats a problem because my script is written in Python 3 and I want to use pandas library in this script. How can I upgrade PyPy to Python 3? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears PyPy is not fully compatible with Python 3.8 just yet. Latest build is up to Python 3.7.9 with 3.8 support still in beta.

Also, there are different version it seems for different Python main versions, i.e PyPy for Python 2.x and PyPy3 for Python 3.x. Make sure you're either installing the combined package or the appropriate version PyPy3.8.

[PyPy download page](https://www.pypy.org/download.html) shows Python 3.8 as a standalone version of PyPy.

Comment: Thanks! I have downloaded PyPy3. How can I install pandas library there? `pypy3 install pandas` does not work

Comment: @vojta From what I gathered, first install pip to pypy3 [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342075/install-pip-on-pypy) (probably have to use `pypy3` rather than `pypy`), then use `pypy3 -m pip install pandas`